# "Saber Wing"... 3/4 or 6/8?

Tags: electronic-music, videogame-soundtrack

*Saber Wing* is a song created by TAG, originating in the game *Dance Dance Revolution X.* It’s the most notable song in the entire franchise that doesn't use a 4/4 time signature, but is it 3/4 or 6/8? [This is the song.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dot5z5YLsuA)

Comment: I hear it as 3/4 (or 3/8), mainly because the bassline accents every third beat equally hard, so it doesn't have that 'lilting' 6/8 feel. On the other hand, the bass drum pattern repeats every 6 beats, so there'd be an argument for 6/8. 

I think there's a bit of 5/4 (or 5/8?) in the middle, too.

Comment: According to the [DDR Wiki](http://dancedancerevolutionddr.wikia.com/wiki/SABER_WING) (and we all know Wiki's are't 100% accurate), it's 3/4.

Comment: This question is more for musicians then music fans and as such I think it would not be on topic here like [identifying chords and notes](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/66/are-identifying-chords-or-notes-in-a-song-on-topic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing the score it could really be either…

However, it's easier to think of it in 6/8, as at about 0:39 it transitions to 5/8  & it's just easier to switch from 6 to 5 in your head when playing, than double-time & simultaneously go from 3 to 5.

Comment: And of course "the score" (as written or ratified by the original composer) in many (most?) cases does not actually exist...

Comment: sure - from head to DAW in one easy step - though… the DAW would have had a time signature set

Comment: ...which in a sequenced track like this is often just a question of "what gives me a usable click" or "what gives me the right snap for my edits/quantisation" - if you're using those things, of course!